# Raw Bitmap Data to Image control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, bitmap, c++-cli

I have a function in my c# WPF Application `DisplayFile` which is meant to populate a `System.Windows.Controls.Image` with a bitmap image.  This bitmap image is loaded from a file supplied by the fileName:

```
public void DisplayFile(System.Windows.Controls.Image imageBox, TextBlock textBox, 
                        String fileName)
    {      
        Bitmap bmp;
        BitmapImage bitmapImage;
        StringBuilder strBldr = new StringBuilder(_ObjFolderPath);
        strBldr.Append(fileName);

        ExtractBitmapAndDescriptor(strBldr.ToString(), out newtext, out bmp);

        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bmp.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            memory.Position = 0;
            bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            bitmapImage.StreamSource = memory;
            bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bitmapImage.EndInit();
        }

        imageBox.Source = bitmapImage;
        textBox.Text = newtext;

    }
```

`ExtractBitmapAndDescriptor` is a function written in a C++/CLI library and is meant to read in the given file and spit out a Bitmap object back into the c# function:

```
void ExtractBitmapAndDescriptor(String ^filePath,[Out] String ^%descriptor,[Out] Bitmap^% bmpIn)
{
    //... Seek through file until Bitmap information reached (File 
        // has an embedded bitmap file     
        //inside with no color pallette and was created using a c++ application)

            // reached bitmap Data
            BITMAPFILEHEADER bfh;
            BITMAPINFO bi;
            fread(&bfh, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, in);
            fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFO)- sizeof(tagRGBQUAD), 1, in);

            BYTE* imageData = (BYTE*) malloc(   bi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage );

            ZeroMemory(imageData, bi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage);
            fread(imageData, bi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage,1, in);               


            bmpIn = gcnew Bitmap((int)bi.bmiHeader.biWidth, (int)bi.bmiHeader.biHeight, (int)bi.bmiHeader.biWidth*3, PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb,IntPtr( ( void * ) imageData ));

            System::Drawing::Rectangle newRect(0,0,bi.bmiHeader.biWidth, bi.bmiHeader.biHeight);
            bmpIn->LockBits(newRect, Imaging::ImageLockMode::ReadOnly,PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb);

    // Parse Other Data and return
}
```

The code gives an exception at 
                   bmp.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Bmp); (DisplayFile function)

that reads:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Rutime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
>
> A generic error occurred in GDI+.

I notice that the rawdata member (non public member) within bmp is null.  I have a suspicion that it is because the raw data passed into the bitmap originally was a managed pointer on unmanaged data and disappeared.  I thought LockBits was supposed to make sure it didn't move, though.

Comment: Why do you need this `c++` code?

Comment: it just happens to be how the file is formatted, there is a lot of other data before and after the embedded bitmap.

Comment: GCar89, and which one is not handled in c#?

Comment: The bottom block of code is C++/CLI

Comment: You should definitely drop that C++ stuff and write a C# method that reads the file. That method could directly create a BitmapSource by one of the BitmapSource.Create methods.

Comment: that is definitely a consideration, but is there not anything I can do with just the raw pixel data and the bitmap info?

Comment: GCar89, `The bottom block of code is C++/CLI` What is it? Bitmap class has a method `LockBits`? I stil don't understand why you need to use c++

Comment: You could also call the [BitmapSource.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.create.aspx) method from C++/CLI and avoid the Bitmap bypass. But honestly, why bother with C++? It's so awkwardly complicated.

Comment: I will try this.  I definitely agree that it is awkward, but I am not too familiar with the File IO stuff in c#.

Comment: Hi guys, I used BitmapSource.Create and got it.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't just use `Image.FromFile` (also, `Path.Combine` instead of your StringBuilder).